# Automated vehicle movements with 9 barcodes

Tags: navigation, barcode, barcode-scanner, vehicle-routing

Of late, I have seen some AGV's working on the model of QR based navigation. However, I saw that the number of barcodes they use is many i.e. 9 (3x3 grid). I am wondering the reason for 9. I can understand the usage of 1 which would give the information about the current location, angle etc.

Answer (score 0):

Might be difficult to get accurate location angle etc from one QR.  If there are many with known coordinates, it is likely more possible to determine the current orientation of the observer in relation to them.